# Too much maxent in text-processing?

Tags: solr, opennlp, text-classification

My name is Frederic and I am no professional developper nor native english speaker so please forgive me for that.

I am actually a medical physician working as an in-hospital clinician and i am passionate in NLP for quite a time now. I'm currently writing a thesis for a MDPHD in medical informatics and my subject is about information retrieval of patient documentation for a better clinical workflow.

I have a quite well defined strategy for text pre-processing and later indexing through Solr. I have been able to implement a max-ent classifier that works great! It works so well actually that is puts into questions other step of text processing (I now kindof want to use it everywhere, which feels totally wrong). And I need your insight for making my mind about that point.

Medical texts are of very different types (specialized consultations, operative documents, prescriptions, notes etc). However, they often follow text structuration rules that are quite general. For example, admissions form always display info about physical examination in the form of a list, and a few paragraphs of narrative text.

I first wanted to use a maxent classifier to classify chunks of text into main headings (Patient info, discipline, physical, discharge summary, discharge prescriptions and so on). That seems to work great! But after a while, I realized that most errors in classification came from the fact that the text was not segmented properly in the first place and thus the maxent could not do its job correctly. I do paragraph segmenting on the basis of a manual decision-tree, taking into account new lines and spacing, and some characteristics of the text preceding or following separation markors (ex: titles are often all-caps, you can differentiate "real new lines" from "decorative new lines" by the presence of a period at the end of preceding paragraph and an upper cased first letter in the one following and so on...).

Well... maxent for this task works well as well. But now I find myself training a third maxent because it works so well and I now want to differentiate real periods from other periods (like in numbers or abbreviations)... and there also is dashes classification.

If I listened to myself (and hopefully i dont), i would use maxent for pretty much every text processing task that requires a bit of classification. But it seems very wrong for many reasons: time for training, memory usage etc...

So could you please give me your advices: For a series of tasks, which would make the most sense to use maxent, and are there alternative that I did not took into account?

Main tasks that are in question now are:

- paragraph segmentation: using maxent to determine if a line-break is
  a real one or should be omitted
- paragraph classification: once
  segmented, give subheading for each paragraphs
- words (or tokens) normalisation:
  real periods VS in-word periods (end of sentence VS abbreviation for
  example), dashes, apostrophes (I work in the french language so these
  characters are quite problematic, like in the words such as "va-t'en"
  or "jusqu'à".

Sorry for the long text. I figured no code was really useful for this question, but i can put some if it can help you help me ;)

Thanx in advance, and cheers,

Comment: This question is too broad for this site and primarily opinion based. I suggest you move it to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @BinoyDalal when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @BinoyDalal "too broad" and "primarily opinion based" are close reasons at Programmers and everywhere else on the SE network. Please do not recommend asking questions on _any_ other site for those reasons.

Comment: @Snowman I suggested programmers because the very description of the site says that it is for conceptual questions about programming which I feel this one is.

Comment: @BinoyDalal from Programmers [help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), it is quite clear that broad and opinionated questions will be closed. I am not sure if you have read the help center there or ever participated because you do not have an account on Programmers that I can see. Which is one more reason not to recommend cross-posting, because you are unfamiliar with the site (gnat and I are veterans there).

Comment: @Snowman That is true. I understand. My bad.

Comment: Ok I m sorry but i couldn't find any other place that seemed to be able to answer to those questions (i mean on the net). And yes, it is probably opinion based. Tell me if I need to move it swhere else.